# Как можно разбить оттенки по цветам?

Tags: алгоритм, изображения, любой-язык, обработка-изображений

Допустим, имеется коллекция пикселей. Как я могу эти пиксели сгруппировать между собой по цветам? Т.е получить цвет и список найденных оттенков?

Цвет отличающийся на несколько значений в rgb понятное дело, что является оттенком. А как быть с более отличными оттенками?

Comment: Как угодно можете сгруппировать, например по расстоянию в модели HSV или любой другой на ваш вкус.

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных и результат на выходе

Comment: Насколько позволяют судить мои познания в данной области, ваша задача сводится к стандартной кластеризации точек в трёхмерном пространстве (если рассматривать как пространственные оси красный-зелёный-синий или яркость-насыщенность-тон).

Comment: @АндрейNOP На вход подается какой-нибудь двумерный массив RGB объектов, а на выходе должно получиться, что-то вроде словаря, где первый элемент- это название цвета, а на второй-это коллекция RGB отттенков.

Comment: Ок, тогда ваша задача сводится к заведению коллекции правил, которые позволят однозначно определить название цвета, например, что #ff00ff — это розовый, а #ff0090 — уже нет. Коллекция будет иметь столько правил, сколько цветов вы хотите отличать друг от друга.

Comment: Вероятно, вместо RGB следует использовать [HSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(цветовая_модель)).

Comment: Если что, в .NET у класса Color есть методы GetHue, GetSaturation, GetBrightness.

Comment: *как быть с более отличными оттенками* - точно так же. Если входит в границы "оттенка", то оттенок этого цвета, если не входит, то уже другой цвет.